# Angular not working with express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an incredibly simple "app" and can not figure out why angular isn't working. The angular code alone works, but when I visit localhost:3000, it doesn't. It does, however, work when I add the angular code at the end of the html file as a script.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Hello from express');
});
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.message = "message from controller";
})
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
      <h3>{{message}}</h3>
    </div>
  </body>

<script>

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the JavaScript file for it to be available.

You can use `express.static('path/to/file')` to serve static resources.

For example:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js/'));
```

The `/js` directory would then be available in your `index.html` file as:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular project should be served as static files.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(3000);
```